Is there an implementation of PriorityBlockingQueue in Java that acts like a FIFO Queue When there are ties?
I have a bunch of threads delivering audio stream frames to a central Java Blocking Queue (currently its FIFO). Think of this as the threads sending Commands to the main thread. Now I need a FLUSH_STREAMS Command. This Command should cause the Command Consumer to dismiss all existing stream commands in the queue (until he receives a START_STREAMS command). The problem with this is the following:
If I keep using a Fifo Queue, the Consumer doesn't react to the FLUSH_STREAMS Command in time, first having to process all existing AUDIO frames.
If I use a priority QUEUE and give the FLUSH_STREAMS command top priority, the AUDIO streams will be out of order, since they all have the same priority.
So I basically need some kind of implementation of PriorityBlockingQUeue that acts like a FIFO Queue when there are elements with the same priority.
Does Java have something like this?

What about adding entries to your priority queue with a timestamp information? You can break the tie with the help of the timestamps.

why not use a (extended) Deque - every time a FLUSH is added, add it to the start, other events are added at the end

I think I would instead reconsider whether audio stream frames and commands should really belong in the same queue. Trying to do both in one queue is a slippery slope, and you may end up locking into a framework that, long term, becomes convoluted e.g. when certain commands need special priority.
You should instead spawn two distinct queues with each their own purpose. One for commands, one for audio stream frames.

is there a clean way to tell Java: Wait for a new Command from either the Command Queue or the Audio Queue. Whichever comes first?

You are trying to merge the two queues to let the commander handle them as one.
With the same argument as above, could the commander just consume both queues separately? That would give you the behaviour you are looking for: The commander consumes whatever comes first.

Yes but it needs to not do anything if theres neither audio nor commands, right? I mean I could have 2 consumers feeding into another queue but that just kicks the can down the road I think

There's no reason why the "priority" that the queue respects is exactly the same thing as the "priority" that serves your application's higher-level needs. A priority queue needs a Comparator. You could provide a Comparator that respects both the application-level priority that you assign to your queued objects, as well as respecting a sequence number stamp that you attach to each object when you put it into the queue.
